# Chapter title in TOC on two lines when using \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents

I am having a problem when adding an unnumbered chapter to the TOC. The section in question is the list of symbols which is in the preliminary pages, before the beginning of the Introduction. The chapter is (title is in french) :

```
\chapter*{Liste des symboles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Liste des symboles}
My list of symbols here
```

Now the problem I face is that the title of the chapter appears incorrectly. It appears on two lines like this:
L........................................i
ste des symboles...........viii

Note : the i on the right is actually from the title and not the pages. Also, the title should have been all CAPS given the definition in the document class (all other chapter titles/introduction/conclusion appear in CAPS in the TOC.

I think the root of my problem might be the fact that the chapters in the TOC are formatted to appear on two lines :
CHAPITRE I
CHAPTER TITLE.................5

but I want the list of symbols to appear on one line like the introduction and cocnlusion:
INTRODUCTION...................1

I tried including it in the full document :

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{memoireuqam1.3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\rot}{O{90} O{1em} m}{\makebox[#2][l]{\rotatebox{#1}{#3}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\addtocounter{page}{1}

\include{thanks}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\parindent=0ex
\include{symbols} %%%%%%%%%%%%%problem section%%%%%%%
\include{abstract}

\parindent=0ex 

\include{Introduction}
\include{chapt1}
\include{chapt2}
\include{chapt3}
\include{conclusion}    

\bibliographystyle{theseuqam}    
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

I am using a class provided by my university for the master's thesis (http://www.labmath.uqam.ca/latex/telecharger.php). Copied below is the part relevant to the TOC :

```
\newcommand\l@specialchapitre {\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{0em}}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \baselineskip=\simpleinter
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
    \parskip=0ex
    \vspace*{-1.5ex}
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \noindent
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    \baselineskip=\doubleinter
    \parskip=2ex}

\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \nopagebreak
      \leavevmode %\bfseries
      \hskip -\leftskip
      \@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{1.5ex}}
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{specialchapitre}
                    {\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp\protect\hskip 0.5em \numerochap} \vskip 0ex
\uppercase{#1}
                     }%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
                    \fi
%                    \newcommand\numerochap{\Roman{chapter}}
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
 %                   \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
 %                   \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi
                    }

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
     \let\@svsec\@empty\else
     \refstepcounter{#1}\edef\@svsec{\csname the#1\endcsname\hskip
1em}\fi
     \@tempskipa #5\relax
      \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
        \begingroup #6\relax
          \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty \@M
#8\par}%
        \endgroup
       \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}
        \ifnum #2<3
         \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{1.5ex}}
         \addcontentsline
         {toc}{#1}{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
                      \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}\fi
                    #7}\else
        \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\relax  %% \relax added 2 May 90
                   \@svsec #8\csname #1mark\endcsname
                      {#7}\addcontentsline
                           {toc}{#1}{\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
                             \protect\numberline{\csname
the#1\endcsname}\fi
                       #7}}\fi
        \fi
     \@xsect{#5}}


\renewcommand\l@section      {\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand\l@subsection   {\@dottedtocline{2}{2.3em}{3.2em}}
\renewcommand\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
```

I would very much appreciate your help. I hope I have provided all the needed information.

Comment: I am unable to verify your problem even with your document class (mind you, I removed the *entire* preamble since it seems to have no bearing on the other components of the document nor the problem at hand). Also, instead of using `\input`, I replaced them with `\chapter` and/or `\chapter*`. Perhaps, with these inconsistencies in mind, create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that one can copy-and-paste and compile without extra files. Also include a screen shot of your current output (even if you don't have enough privileges, include the link to an image).

Comment: @Werner I'll get on that MWE tonight after work. I managed to "trick" LaTeX by writing the symbols in the abstract environment and renaming abstract to List of Symbols just before including it.